# selenium webdriver ruby clear browser localstorage

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

is there a way to clear the localstorage when running a test in selenium when using ruby? I have a login that will add key value to localstorage and I need that cleared before running each test. Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about the cookies?

Comment: No, the HTML5 LocalStorage API.

Comment: @oertrai1 - Did you get a resolution to this query?

Comment: @nids - No I never did get any resolution on this :-(

Comment: Good question, looking for a solution to this using capybara.

Answer (score 0):

This page has some information on how to use JavaScript to modify local storage: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/selenium-users/html5/selenium-users/qahuzVl1svQ/hR6FO3GGzDMJ.

The example is in Java, but the basic idea should work in any language since you ultimately use JavaScript in the browser.

```
this.executeJavascript(String.format("window.localStorage.clear();"));
```

Just tried it with WebDriverJS in Chrome and it seems to work.

Comment: ` $driver.execute_script("localStorage.clear()");' does not work in Chrome.  You get this error:      ` (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322455 (ae8db840dac8d0c453355d3d922c91adfb61df8f),platform=Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoScriptResultError)'

Comment: I think the point from above was to use window.localStorage and not localStorage directly. I read somewhere that localStorage does not work wirh Selenium if accessed that way

Comment: I have an error A JavaScript exception occurred: The operation is insecure.